# Jquery blur and focus causes type error "this.trigger" is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the page there are many buttons and they are setup in the same way, yet some actually cause a TypeError, when `focus()` or `blur()` is called. The error happens inside jquery (3.6.0).

**Here is the code from jquery where the type error happens:**

```
S.each("blur focus focusin focusout resize scroll click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup contextmenu".split(" "), function (e, n) {
    S.fn[n] = function (e, t) {
        return 0 < arguments.length ? this.on(n, null, e, t) : this.trigger(n)
    }

jquery-3.6.0.js?v=638024629878907069:3228 Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger is not a function
at S.fn.<computed> (jquery-3.6.0.js?v=638024629878907069:3228:73)
```

Does anyone have an explanation on why does this happen everytime, but only on some buttons and/or elements?

Comment: There error would be somewhere in your code, most likely the `.trigger()` you call is not on an jquery element. Without seeing your code we can't tell for sure

Comment: none of the elements have trigger specifically set up on them, yet it works on 99% of them. As far as I know trigger is also applied with things like click event. Which is definetly setup on the buttons that have this issue @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: did you use `S` instead of `$` on purpose? and I'm ignoring the missing closing brackets because probably it's just a question posted in the rush

Comment: @DiegoD that code example is copied from JQuery itself. My code is simply calling .blur() or .focus() on a jquery element

Comment: Give us a proper [mre] of the issue then. We can't debug "only on some" without any relevant details.

Comment: @CBroe I cant reproduce it in fiddler, not even on my page on purpose. If i could i would know what causes it. All buttons are setup in the same way so i have no idea how to reproduce it.

Comment: Then you can't expect us to be able to do much here either though. I'd start by debugging what `this` actually is in the instances where it errors then.

Comment: that code example is from Jquery @CBroe, from the actual jquery js file

Comment: Yes, and? Doesn't stop you from temporarily modifying the code in that place to get a console.log or something, does it?

Comment: @CBroe when .blur() is called I check on the element if it has .trigger() function and it does, but when the code is stopped in the specified jquery code its undefined. `this` in that case the correct element.